# How to call methods on Collective pallet from a custom pallet?

Tags: loose-coupling, pallet-collective

I need to call methods in the *Collective* pallet to:

- get a list of council members
- create a new *Proposal*
- propose the proposal

BUT from my custom pallet.

```
/// Function in my custom pallet
#[pallet::call_index(0)]
#[pallet::weight(1000)]
 pub fn do_something(
  origin: OriginFor<T>
 ) -> DispatchResult {

  let council_members = CollectivePalletInterface::members();
  let first_member = council_members.into_iter().next();

... etc ...

}
```

I have seen some of the documentation for loosely coupled pallets but I have not been able to get it to work.  The example that I have seen requires that the coupled pallet already have traits that you can import into your custom pallet.  The *Collective* pallet defines a single trait that doesn't contain any of the functionality that I need.  One drastic approach would be to create a new custom pallet based on the *Collective* pallet source code, implement traits for it and then use it.

I would prefer a loosely coupled approach.  What can I do?  If it's possible, show me how I can, for example, access all the *Council* members and print the address of the first member.

Answer (score 2):

If the target pallet doesn't provide a trait. You can do:

```rs
pub trait Config: pallet_collective::Config { ... }

...

let council_members = pallet_collective::Members::get();
```

or

```rs
// in your pallet
pub trait Config {
  type GetMembers: frame_support::traits::Get<Vec<Self::AccoundId>>;
}

...

let council_members = T::GetMembers::get();

// in runtime
frame_support::construct_runtime! {
  Council: pallet_collective
}
impl pallet_collective::Config for Runtime { ... }
pub struct GetMembers;
impl Get<Vec<AccountId>> for GetMembers {
  fn get() -> Vec<AccountId> {
    Council::members()
  }
}
impl your_pallet::Config for Runtime {
  type GetMembers = GetMembers;
}
```